# How would I put an "if" statement into this code to check for non-alphabet characters?

Tags: c

The code is for turning alphabet numbers from lower case to upper case and vice versa; however if non-alphabet characters are inserted it should return an error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int c = 0;
    char ch, s[1000];

    printf("Enter a string of upper and lower case letters\n");
    scanf("%s", s);
}
```

Comment: Before inserting any `if` you'll need a loop to contain it. Then explore functions `isupper()` and `tolower()` etc.

Comment: `if ((somechar => 'A' && somechar <= 'Z') || (somechar => 'a' && somechar <= 'z')) {it's a character from the alphabet}`. Or use [`isalpha`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) and friends

Comment: @Jabberwocky Why? There is `isaplha` function.

Comment: Not even that: `if(isupper(..)) {} else if(islower(...)) {} else { /* error */}`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know, I edited the comment. But as he's a absolute beginner, I think it's worth to show also how to do it "by hand"

Answer (score 2):

Always protect your code from bufffer overflows:

```
scanf("%999s", s);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%s", s);
```

regarding your question, you can use `isalpha` and `tolower`, `toupper`:

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
scanf("%999s", s);

char *p = s;

while (*p)
{
    unsigned char c = (unsigned char)*p;

    if (!isalpha(c))
    {
        // there are non alpha chars
        // return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        *p = islower(c) ? toupper(c) : tolower(c);
    }
    p++;
}
```

Comment: Why do you (correctly) cast to `unsigned char` before passing the value of `*p` to `isalpha`, but not do the same for `islower`, `toupper` and `tolower`? This will cause undefined behavior if `*p` is negative (unless it happens to be `EOF`). Instead of casting four times, it may be easier to cast once to a temporary `int` variable.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel if `isalpha` returns true then there is no need to cast the rest of the calls, the `char` is for sure in the range [`'a'` ...  `'z'`] or [`'A'` - `'Z'`]

Comment: The function [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) can also return true for characters `> 127` if a locale other than `"C"` is used.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel if `char` > 127 then plain `char` would be `unsigned char` and can not be negative, thus there is no need to cast in this case.

Comment: I was referring to the codes of the character map, not the actual value of `*p`. Characters whose codes are `>127` in the character map will be stored as negative values in `*p`, assuming that the compiler uses signed `char` (most compilers do). The function `isalpha` can return true also for negative values of `*p`. In that case, you call `islower` with a negative value. This causes undefined behavior according to [§7.4 ¶1 of the ISO C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4), unless that negative value happens to be `EOF`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I know what you mean and you make me doubt, I'm gonna check it in deep, but for what I understand, after the filtering there is no chance to get values outside of the range of `isalpha` and the cast is not necessary (even if some exoteric value is passed)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel anyway I edit the answer with you suggestion, thanks!

Comment: Your code looks good now after your edit. In practice, this probably would never have caused any trouble, because both the Microsoft C Runtime Library and the GNU C Library also allow negative values for all of these functions (even though the ISO C standard does not). Most other libraries are probably also tolerant in this respect.

Comment: However, even if most standard library implementations are tolerant in this respect, it can still be important to cast to `unsigned char`, because if you don't, the standard library has no way of distinguishing `EOF` from an actual character. For example, if `EOF` is defined as `-1`, then the standard library has no way of distinguishing it from the character number 255, so the standard library will have to treat that character the same as `EOF` (for example by treating it as non-alphabetical, even if it is). This problem doesn't exist if you do it the proper way.